# C - Linked list printing in the wrong order

Tags: c, loops, printing, linked-list, iteration

I have created a linked list whose elements are strings acquired from command line arguments:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    struct element_Args {
        char commandLineArgs[500];
    };


    struct list {

    struct element_Args element;
    struct list *next;
    };

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct list *head;
    struct list *current;

    head = (struct list *) malloc(sizeof(struct list));


    head->next = NULL;

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        current = malloc (sizeof(struct list));
        strcpy(current->element.commandLineArgs, argv[i]);
        current->next = head;
        head = current;

    }

    current = head;

    while(current->next != NULL) {
       printf("%s\n", current->element.commandLineArgs);
       current = current->next;
    }

    return 0;

    }
```

However, when I print the elements in the linked list, they are printing out in the reverse order from which they were entered as arguments.  How can I print them in the same order in which they were entered?  I feel as though I'm missing something small, but I can't figure out what that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your for loop, remove `head = current`.

Basically, you're losing track of your head by using this line. You can later traverse the `head` by setting temp pointers, but don't reset the `head` (unless you're inserting a new `head`).

To insert a new head you would say, `newHead->next = head;` `head = newHead;` If you want to insert them in order, you should keep a tail pointer and always add at the end.

```
int i;
struct list* tail = head;
for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    current = malloc (sizeof(struct list));
    if(current != NULL){
        strcpy(current->element.commandLineArgs, argv[i]);
        tail->next =  current; // add this line
        tail = tail->next;
        current->next = head; //this line makes you add in reverse order. Remove this as well.

        head = current; // remove this line here
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem

```
head = current;
```

you should make `head` point to the first node, and never overwrite it again.

So in your code, `head` is actually the `tail` from that it is logical that the values are printed in the reverse order, it's not reverse you expect the reverse of it.

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct element_Args {
    char commandLineArgs[500];
};


struct list {

struct element_Args element;
struct list *next;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct list *head;
    struct list *current;
    struct list *last;
    int i;

    head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
    if (head == NULL)
        return -1;
    head->next = NULL;

    last = head;
    for(i = 0 ; i < argc ; i++) {
        current = malloc (sizeof(*current));
        if (current != NULL) {

            strcpy(current->element.commandLineArgs, argv[i]);

            last->next = current;
            last       = current;
        }
    }

    current = head;
    while(current != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", current->element.commandLineArgs);
        current = current->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to write a `freeList()` function to `free` all the `malloc`ed stuff.

Comment: So make head point to the first node before the for loops starts?

Comment: Yes an never change it again, keep track of the `previous` node, and make `current` `previous`'s `next`, then make `current` `previous`.

Comment: I see.  I'll go over this.  Thanks!